# How to converting JSON Array to JAVASCRIPT Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a question regarding array. I have a JSON output passing from PHP. My output is like below:

```
[{"Month":"Value Transactions"},{"6":"0.70"},{"7":"10.92"},{"8":"5.60"},{"9":"1.70"}]
```

I know maybe my question is duplicated. But I already find the solution but can't find it. I need the above JSON to be convert like below using javascript:

```
[ ["Month", "Value Transactions"], [6, 0.70], [7, 10.92], [8, 5.60], [9, 1.70] ]
```

How can I achieve this. Please help and thank you.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Seems like you want to get the entries of each object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: For one you can use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` in `json_encode` to not output numbers as strings. Can you change the PHP? Or is it fixed?

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i don't know how to do that. can you please give the sample code. I am beginner in Javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Note: coercing the number strings to a float will drop any extraneous zeros.

```js
const data = [{"Month":"Value Transactions"},{"6":"0.70"},{"7":"10.92"},{"8":"5.60"},{"9":"1.70"}];

// If the parsed value is not a number return the value
// otherwise coerce it to an number
const getValue = (v) => Number.isNaN(parseFloat(v)) ? v : +v;

// `map` over the array objects
const out = data.map(obj => {

  // Extract the key and values from each object
  const [[ key, val ]] = Object.entries(obj);

  // Return an array with the correct values/types
  return [ getValue(key), getValue(val) ];
});

console.log(out);
```

Further reading:

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Sir OP wants `0.70` and in your code it only `0.7` . I know that zero doesn't matter but then too look at your code sir .

Comment: It's clear he wants floating point numbers. Losing those zeros is the side effect of that. fwiw I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer.